# Why redis command ‘LLEN’ has constant time complexity instead of O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, redis, time-complexity, big-o

I know that redis list is implemented by linked list under the hood. However when calculating time complexity of length of the list, shouldn’t it be O(n)？

Comment: What makes you think it is calculated every time?
It is common for data structures to incorporate a "length" variable which is adjusted every time the structure is modified in time complexity at most equal to the complexity of the modifying algorithm. This way, every time you want to know the length, the data structure simply reads the value of that variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the declaration of the list type at https://github.com/redis/redis/blob/unstable/src/adlist.h.  If you look at the section around line 50 you find:

```
typedef struct list {
    listNode *head;
    listNode *tail;
    void *(*dup)(void *ptr);
    void (*free)(void *ptr);
    int (*match)(void *ptr, void *key);
    unsigned long len;
} list;
```

Note the `unsigned long len` that stores the length of the list.  That is why it is `O(1)`.